# Why this program find only one solution?

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, latin-square

I want to code a program which finds all solutions for latin square. I want to do it using backtracking. I solved the n-queens problem using a similar method and it works.
This code finds only the first solution and it doesn't back track.

```
public static boolean isSafe(int[][] board, int row, int col) {

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if(row != i) {
            if(board[i][col] == board[row][col]) return false;
        }
        if(col != i) {
            if(board[row][i] == board[row][col]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void enumerate(int N) {
    int[][] board = new int[N][N];
    enumerate(board, 0, 0);
}

public static void enumerate(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    int boardSize = board.length;
    if (col == boardSize ) {
        System.out.println();
        print(board);
        SaveToFile.saveSquare("Latin", "BT", board, boardSize);

    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= boardSize; i++) {
            board[row][col] = i; 
            if (isSafe(board, row, col)) {
                if(row+1 == boardSize) {
                    enumerate(board, 0, col+1);
                }
                else {
                    enumerate(board, row+1, col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void print(int[][] board) {
    for(int i=0; i<board.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<board.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" "+board[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 2; i <=2; i++) {
        SaveToFile.createFile("Latin", "BT", i);
        enumerate(i);
    }
}
```

I know that my code looks bad but I'll refactor it later ;)
thanks for help :)

Comment: Unrelated: *I know that my code looks bad* ... but you think it is polite asking other people to read it then? And well, do you think you would need other people to tell what the code you wrote is (not) doing ... if you had spend more time on writing code that you understand? But seriously: it ain't that bad. I have seen much much worse newbie code here ;-)

Comment: The loop in `main` does not loop much. Is that what is intended?

Comment: I agree 100% with u comment, but I had to write something because I could't add this post without it;)

Comment: Shouldn't you reset `board[row][col]` sometimes? You set it to `i`, and then that value stays.

Comment: @arndtJonasson Here I test program for only one value. Generally I use it to run program for diffrent values.

Comment: something like this:
if (isSafe(board, row, col)) {
                 //DO SOMETHING
                }else {
                 board[row][col] = 0;
                }
? I tried it. Didn't help

Comment: @arndtJonasson you was right, additional I must resel value after recuirsive too. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the value you are setting in the board after the recursive calls:

```
public static void enumerate(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    int boardSize = board.length;
    if (col == boardSize ) {
        System.out.println();
        print(board);
        SaveToFile.saveSquare("Latin", "BT", board, boardSize);

    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= boardSize; i++) {
            board[row][col] = i;
            if (isSafe(board, row, col)) {
                if(row+1 == boardSize) {
                    enumerate(board, 0, col+1);
                }
                else {
                    enumerate(board, row+1, col);
                }
            }
            //RESET!!!
            board[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```